# set compression headers and compress , caching headers?

Tags: php, http-headers

What headers should a send with an image output (image.php when opened allows user to download an image) to set caching time for that image to 3 days (instead of re-downloading the image from the user side) ??

and how can i compress the image and send it compressed and what headers should i send along to tell the browser that this image is compressed ?

thank you .

Comment: Do you mean a real download or just an implicit download (like every  resource is downloaded by browser)?

Comment: Re-compressing images with HTTP Compression (GZIP or DEFLATE) typically makes them larger, and should thus be avoided.

Comment: @EricLaw -MSFT-, care to explain or provide a link?

Comment: Eric is 100% correct. "Image and PDF files should not be gzipped because they are already compressed. Trying to gzip them not only wastes CPU but can potentially increase file sizes." http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the easiest way to compress is to enabled deflate or gzip from the htaccess level if you're running apache. If not, you can add the `ob_gzhandler()` function as the `ob_start()` callback at the beginning of the document like so:

```
<?php
if( !ob_start("ob_gzhandler") ) {
    ob_start();
}
//Feel free to echo image data and whatnot, the callback deals with the headers, compatibility, and compression!
?>
```

Note this requires the [zlib](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zlib.php) extension.

You can also [add this function as the ob callback in the php.ini file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-handler) or enable the [zlib.output_compression](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php#ini.zlib.output-compression) directive.

As for setting up caching, simply add this `header()` call before outputting text:

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: max-age='.(5184000 * 3).', must-revalidate'); //Cache should last for 3 days
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

these headers should be fine

- Age:XXXXXX
- Cache-Control:max-age=259200
- Content-Length:XXXXXX
- Content-Type:image/XXXXXX
- Date:Sat, XXXXXX
- Etag:XXXXXX
- Last-Modified:XXXXXX